# Why can't I resolve a promise by calling its resolver from within an array?

Tags: javascript, promise

The code can be found at my repo [here](https://github.com/barberousse/async-toolkit/blob/master/index.js), but I'll paste:

```
function asyncQueue() {
  'use strict'
  let i = -1
  let j = 0
  const resolvers = []

  function put (p) {
    if (!p.then) 
      p = Promise.resolve(p)

    if (resolvers[j] instanceof Array) {
      const done = resolvers[j][0]
      const fail = resolvers[j][1]
      p.then( a => done(a) ).catch( e => fail(e) )
    } else {
      resolvers[j] = p
    }

    ++j
  }

  function get() {
    ++i
    if (resolvers[i] instanceof Promise) 
      return resolvers[i]

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => resolvers[i] = [resolve, reject] )
  }

  return { 
    get: get, 
    put: put
  }
}
```

The catch is that the, as of Node 5.4, if we alter the Put function like so:

```
    if (resolvers[j] instanceof Array) {
      p.then( a => resolvers[j][0](a) ).catch( e => resolvers[j][1](e) )
    } else {
      resolvers[j] = p
    }
```

The promise those resolvers belong to *never* fulfill. WAT?!

I spent an hour trying to figure what the hell I was doing wrong, but then decided to just bind the resolver refs and move on. Would anyone have any idea why calling the functions inline from within the array poo poos? I've observed that `a` is the value we expect, but passing it to the resolver in this way leaves the owner Promise within a pending state, as if I never fired the resolver.

Comment: What is asyncQueue for? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: WAT it is...it's like the whole 'what you shouldn't do' in one piece of code. :)

Comment: Why do you dislike semi-colons so much...

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Because to me, its easier to read w/o than with

Comment: @elclanrs https://kriskowal.gitbooks.io/gtor/content/async-queues.html

Comment: But this forces the parser to insert them and can cause issues.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss At my job we've just finished alpha for an entire multimedia sequencer in the browser in React. No semicolons; no problems. Its not as big a deal as its made out to be. Read here http://mislav.net/2010/05/semicolons/

Comment: @Microfed You don't know what you're talking about

Comment: @elclanrs Basically you can use it as foundational abstraction for a stream buffer, amongst other things

Comment: While it doesn't explain the problem, you should just be doing `Promise.resolve(p).then(resolvers[j][0], resolvers[j][1]);` anyway. Or even better, simply `resolvers[j][0](p);` (and nothing else, you don't even need a rejecter).

Comment: @Bergi Wow, must simpler. Thank you, will do!

Comment: I don't understand why people feel the need to express their opinions on the code or worse the code style (this question has NOTHING to do with semi-colons) rather than answer the question.

Flagging feels too harsh, but there should be a way to down vote a comment.

Comment: @BigAB a code is never broken. It's just our understanding of the code is not always well enough. I had tried to answer and then I understood that the main reason of "not working" is the quality. The code above haven't been written with intention to clarity. Because of that it's so hard to understand how it actually works. I've seen this kind of things (promise based queues, streams) implemented in Javascript. It could be done in a much better way, where there is no place for an error to hide.

Answer (score 1):

** **EDIT: Typos were a red herring, so I added a new answer answering your actual question, why the promise wasn't getting resolved** **

To answer your question:
You have a typo on lines 12 and 13:

```
const done = resolver[j][0]
const fail = resolver[j][1]
```

If you change those to `resolvers` (add an s), your test passes on node 5.5

You may be thinking it didn't resolve, because if you were to say:

```
q = asyncQueue()
x = q.get()
q.put(1)
x.then(value => console.log(value))
```

Your console would have two lines:

```
Promise { <pending> }
1
```

Because that last line is actually returning a new promise as well, that wont resolve until after the consoles default behavior of logging return values.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typos, but did you call the resolvers inline from the array? The typos are just typos, I had the code with the correct variable names prior and got the output the you have just fine. But when if I called the resolvers in this fashion -> p.then( a => resolver[j][0](a) ).catch( e => resolver[j][1](e) ) <- I did not get that output, in fact, not ever logged, the promise was still pending

Comment: I edited my post for clarity and to indicate that the typos are not the contributor to the problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now that I understand your question more and the typos were resolved, I'll try to answer again.

> Would anyone have any idea why calling the functions inline from within the array poo poos?

It has to do with the closure over `j`.

In the first example, you are resolving `resolvers[j][0]` **synchronously**, before the `++j` that comes at the end of `.put()`.

When you **"inline"** the access to the resolvers, by which I mean, use the `j` key to access the resolvers on `resolvers` *inside* the promises, they are happening **asynchronously** (like on the next tick sort of), *after* the `++j`, so you are accessing an empty array index and calling it as a function.

The reason it "fails silently", or never resolves is that, the catch in put only ends up throwing another "function is undefined" error, which could be caught, except for the `p` created is never referenced again and is just discarded, so the promise created with `.get()`, never resolves or rejects.